# Is the floor function increasing or decreasing or both in the interval [0,1)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I was attempting a quiz in which I encountered this question, Now the graph of the floor function is constant in the interval $[0,1)$ so technically the function should be neither increasing nor decreasing, but the answer to the question is its both increasing and decreasing. So is the answer wrong or am I unaware of a concept?

Similarly, there was another question about the function $f(x)=x^2 -3x +2$ in the interval $[0,inf]$ but the graph of the function comes down from 0 and there is a critical point at 1 and then goes up, so is decreasing and increasing in the interval $[0,inf)$ but the answer is its neither increasing nor decreasing, now one of my classmates gave me a line of reasoning that $f'(x)<=0  and f'(x)>=0$ in the inerval $[0,inf)$ which implies $f'(x)=0$ but I'm not really convinced with the argument because the graph clearly shows that the function is decreasing then increasing. So am I missing a concept here or the answers are wrong?

I tried to understand the arguments given in [Can a function be increasing or decreasing at a point?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565229/can-a-function-be-increasing-or-decreasing-at-a-point) this question but couldn't really make the comparisons, can someone help me here? Or suggest me some text to clarify this?

Comment: The floor function on $[0,1)$ is identically $0$. What is your definition of increasing or decreasing? Are you going with **strict** increase/decrease or **weak/monotone** increase/decrease? If its the latter then the floor function is both increasing and decreasing (weakly/monotonically), but if its the former then the floor function is neither increasing nor decreasing (strictly).

Answer (score 2):

increasing function: $x>y$ $\implies$ $f(x)\ge f(y)$

decreasing function: $x>y$ $\implies$ $f(x)\le f(y)$

strictly increasing function: $x>y$ $\implies$ $f(x)> f(y)$

strictly decreasing function: $x>y$ $\implies$ $f(x)< f(y)$

A constant function is increasing and decreasing. But it is neither strictly increasing nor strictly decreasing.

For $f(x)=x^2-3x+2$, it is increasing on $[1.5,\infty)$ and decreasing on $[0,1.5]$. But it is neither increasing nor decreasing on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Should the second and fourth definitions say "decreasing" rather than "increasing"?

Comment: *"decreasing" and "strictly decreasing" for the second and fourth rows.

Comment: Amended. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, yes. I guess I mixed up neither increasing nor decreasing and a constant function. Thank you for clearing my doubt. CYAries and 
 @Dave